# What should I do if the following error is reported when I use SQLDriverConnect to connect to the openGaus database?

Tags: odbc, unixodbc, open-gauss

What should I do if the following error is reported when I use SQLDriverConnect to connect to the openGaus database?

> [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib
> /home/centos/opengauss/odbc/lib/psqlodbca.so' : file not found

Answer (score 0):

1. first check auth  "  /home/centos/opengauss/odbc/lib/ "
   ** you need to backup this folder before test if you think it is not risky

   for test give 777 auth to directory and access
2. reference

https://opengauss.org/en/docs/1.0.0/docs/Developerguide/configuring-a-data-source-in-the-linux-os.html